# Not apply dynamic class in react js rendering

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am applying class on condition based but it is not apply. But when I apply class name static then it is applied successfully.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  labelsuccess: {
    "background-color": "#5cb85c"
  },
  labelprogress: {
    "background-color": "#f0ad4e"
  }
});

let labelcolor = [
            {
              status: "In Progress",
              class: "classes.labelprogress"
            },
            {
              status: "Completed",
              class: "classes.labelsuccess"
            }
          ];

{Developertasklist.map((task, index) => (
  <ListItem key={index} divider="true">
    <div className={classes.taskwidth}>
      <span className={classes.hideelement}>
        {
          (foundValue = labelcolor.filter(
            obj => obj.status === task.status
          )[0].class)
        }
      </span>

      <ListItemText
        primary={
          <React.Fragment>
            {task.name} - {task.due_date}
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        secondary={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              className={foundValue}
              color="textPrimary"
            >
              {task.status}
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

Why dynamic class does not apply?

Answer (score 0):

set your variable before the return. Not inside.

with arrow functions, you doesn't need use return if you use brackets like this `() => ( ... )`, but if you want to set variable or calculating, use with curly brackets and return statement. like this;

`() => {
    const a = 'variable';
    return ( <div class={a}>... );
}`

try this one.

```
{Developertasklist.map((task, index) => {
 const foundValue = labelcolor.filter(
     obj => obj.status === task.status
 )[0].class;
 return (
  <ListItem key={index} divider="true">
    <div className={classes.taskwidth}>

      <ListItemText
        primary={
          <React.Fragment>
            {task.name} - {task.due_date}
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        secondary={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography
              component="span"
              className={foundValue}
              color="textPrimary"
            >
              {task.status}
            </Typography>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  </ListItem>
)}
)}
```

Comment: I am trying this code but not working to apply class. when apply dynamic class and inspect element then element like <span class="classes.labelsuccess">Completed</span> and when apply static class and inspect element then element  look like <span class="DeveloperTasks-labelsuccess-13zw7wv">Completed</span>

Comment: can I see your class name you want to render and your tried render way?

Comment: I apply static class like className={classes.labelsuccess} and using dynamic like className={foundValue}

Comment: what you want to see of class name in inspector? use it in labelColor array

Comment: No I do not want to see class name in inspector but I just explain you that what is rendering in inspector when I apply static and dynamic class.